# Can you get a 10 with the Clockwork Amulet after rolling?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Can you use the amulet after rolling the die?

Or should you use the amulet before rolling the die?

I see some forums saying you can change the die after rolling.

> **Clockwork Amulet**
>
> […]
>
> When you make an attack roll while wearing the amulet, you can forgo rolling the d20 to get a 10 on the die. […]

Answer (score 11):

#### “Forgo rolling” requires that you haven’t rolled yet.

Forgo means:

> omit or decline to take (something pleasant or valuable); go without.

If you have already rolled, it’s too late to forgo rolling. You can only forgo rolling if you haven’t rolled yet, since “forgo rolling” means “omit, decline, or go without rolling”.

So you may choose to take 10 *only before you roll.*